# My GameScene is returning nil when I try to use it in GameViewController

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error, null, option-type

I'm creating a basic spaceship game using Swift, and everything was working well until I tried to add a feature where the spaceship moves up every time the user swipes up. I added a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and connected it with an IBAction in my GameViewController, from which I then intended to call a method in my GameScene to make the spaceship move up.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    let scene: GameScene!

    @IBAction func swipeUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        scene.movePlaneUp()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            let skView = self.view as SKView
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and the app runs, however, whenever I try to swipe up, I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the line

```
scene.movePlaneUp()
```

I understand that the error occurs because scene's value was nil, but how do I make it so that scene actually has a value of GameScene?

Here is my code for GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
        bg.size = self.frame.size
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(bg)
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        sprite.xScale = 0.6
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)+CGRectGetMaxY(sprite.frame))
        sprite.name = "spaceship"
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var t = touches.allObjects[0]
        let location = t.locationInNode(self)
        let action = SKAction.moveToX(location.x, duration:0.1)
        let n = self.childNodeWithName("spaceship")
        n?.runAction(action)
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        bullet.xScale = 0.05
        bullet.yScale = 0.05
        bullet.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: 200+bullet.position.y)
        bullet.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(1000, duration: 0.75))
        self.addChild(bullet)
    }
    func movePlaneUp(){
        let n = childNodeWithName("spaceship")
        n?.removeAllActions()
        let action = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100), duration: 1)
        n?.runAction(action)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the reason I had the error was because I never assigned anything to scene. I solved my problem by changing

```
let scene: GameScene!
```

to

```
let myScene: GameScene!
```

then I changed my viewDidLoad to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
        myScene = scene
    }
}
```

which then actually assigned a value to myScene

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late... if you used `self.scene = scene` it would have worked as well. It's due to the `scene` var, created with `if let scene`, overriding any other variable with the same name within the `if let` scope.  You probably already know this now (as it's been two years since this was created) :) However, I hope it's useful to newcomers to the language.